# How can I get the next (x) number of children/siblings of a particular element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is just an illustrative example, but say I had a list of divs containing elements:

```
<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>

<div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

My aim is to run a loop that goes through each div, gets the first 2 children and applies a particular CSS class to them.

How would I go about achieving this?

*Note that this might not necessarily be two elements, at a later date it may become the first ten elements (or more).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div > :lt(2)').addClass(...);
```

The [`:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) uses zero-based indicies.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to do it this way:

```
$('div p').slice(0,2).css('color','red')
```

This is actually the preferred way because `lt(2)` is not a native CSS selector so you lose some efficiency in the query.

> Because :lt() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :lt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lt` jQuery selector

```
$('div p:lt(2)').each(function(index, value) {
    // do something with $(value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) followed by [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
var childCount = 2;
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).children().slice(0, childCount).addClass("yourClass");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with nested loops:

```
var amt = 2;

$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).children().each(function(index, item){
        if(index == amt) return false;
        $(this).addClass('something');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your markup you can try this to select the first childrens

```
$('div > :lt(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var c = $(this).children();
    for(var i=0; i < 2 && i < c.length; i++)
        $(c[i]).html(i);
});
```